# exists, but doesn't declare class Code Igniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class

I try to load this model named "m_cart", but it doesn't work on my controller. I got an error here "M_cart.php exists, but doesn't declare class M_cart"

1. Controller Part.php

```
    <?php

class Cart extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('M_cart');
        $this->load->session('cart');
    }
```

2. Model m_cart.php

```
     <?php
    class Cart_model extends CI_Model{

        function get_all_produk(){
            $hasil=$this->db->get('produk');
            return $hasil->result();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Controller name should be `Cart.php` not `Part.php` if you are declaring `class Cart`(don't forget to extend `CI_Controller`).
2. The m in `m_cart` should be capitalized both in the file name `M_cart.php` and declaration and should extend `CI_Model` e.g. `class M_cart extends CI_Model`.

If both fail to work, verify verify verify that you are editing the same copies as you are testing .etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your model must be declared as a class that extends `CI_Model`

```
Class M_cart extends CI_Model
{

    function get_all_produk()
    {
        $hasil=$this->db->get('produk');
        return $hasil->result();
    }

    function some_other_model()
    {
        // some other thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

class Cart extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('cart_model');
        $this->load->session('cart');
    }
```

this is where your problem is coming from, you did not put the right model name. you used `m_cart` instead of `cart_model`.